# Create an object out of every file imported

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm importing a group of files from a directory using

```
from xyz import *
```

Lets assume my file structure is as follows

```
xyz
|
|---x.py
|---y.py
|---z.py
```

x,y and z are all children of the same class.

Is there a way to make a list of all objects of the imports I made, so I can create objects of x,y and z?

To specify, I want to access the Objects of the classes in the directory structure.

Output

```
[X,Y,Z] #classes from the import
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the `from xyz import *` (which you shouldn't anyway), use the simple `import xyz`. Now you can iterate over `dir(xyz)`:

```
import xyz
objs = [getattr(xyz, obj)() for obj in dir(xyz)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xyz directory, add a `__init__.py` file containing the `__all__` variable:

```
__all__ = ["x", "y", "z"]
```

See also http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I already have an `__all__` variable to do the * import. How would I access the `__all__` variable independent of the directory though? This imports everything, but doesn't put the classes in a list.